# Collect Search Statistics

Tags: 2010, search, statistics

Is there a way to collect all the search strings used by users of a site?

This would preferably be ordered by number of times searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with SharePoint Web Analytics. This should be in your Site Settings. Site Collection Root -> Site Actions Menu -> Site Settings -> Site Collection Web Analytics Reports. The report should be called Top Queries

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663487.aspx

Comment: Are the Top Queries available in SharePoint Foundation aswell?

Comment: Web Analytics are only available in Standard and Enterprise. See here: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx